# What effect do neutral buffs have in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know it is desired to get the blue buff for Ability Power (AP)-base champions and the red buff for Attack Damage (AD)-base champions and baron buff is good for everybody. I think blue buff at least increases your mana regeneration and red buff your health regeneration. So far I don't have any experience with maps (and therefore its buffs) other than Summoners Rift - I would like to know about these too.

What do the buffs affect in detail (preferring concrete numbers)?

Comment: Since it wasn't specifically pointed out in an answer, red buff does not affect health regeneration.

Comment: NOTE: This has been changed with the new preseason 5 jungle update. Red buff *does* grant some HP regen now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Summoners Rift buffs:

**Information applies to *Pre*-season 5 and can be subject to change**

---

#### [Crest of Cinders](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Blessing_of_the_Lizard_Elder) (Red buff)

Granted by killing the Red Brambleback in either the Northern or Southern jungle.

- Basic attacks slow the target's movement speed by (8-15)% for melee attacks and (5-10)% for ranged attacks for 3 seconds.
- Basic attacks also deal 5-56 true damage over 3 seconds.
- Grants health regeneration bonus of 1% maximum health every 5 seconds

#### [Crest of Insight](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crest_of_the_Ancient_Golem) (Blue buff)

Granted by killing the Blue Sentinel in either the Eastern or Western jungle.

- Regenerates 25 mana per 5 seconds
- Regenerates .5% maximum mana (or energy) per second
- 10% cool-down reduction.
- Increases Max Energy (Cannot find source saying exact amount)

*Both red and blue buffs last for 2 minutes without [Runic Affinity](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Runic_Affinity) and 2:24 minutes with it.*

*If slain, buffs held by the newly dead transfer to the killer.*

#### [Hand of Baron](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hand_of_Baron)

- Grants up to 40 AD and AP scaling with game time
- Grants Empowered Recall reducing its channel time to 4 seconds. Successfully recalling will restore 50% of your maximum health and mana and grant 50% bonus movement speed for 8 seconds.
- Buffs all nearby minions and super minions (exact information can be found in the link).

*Lasts for 3 minutes with or without Runic Affinity.*

*If slain, the buff is lost but not transferred unlike the blue and red buffs.*

#### [Dragon Slayer](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Slayer)

This is a permanent team-wide buff that stacks with the number of your team's dragon kills.

1. Dragon's Might: +6% attack damage and ability power
2. Dragon's Wrath: +15% damage to towers and buildings
3. Dragon's Flight: +5% movement speed
4. Dragon's Dominance: +15% damage to minions and monsters
5. Aspect of the Dragon: Doubles all previous bonuses and your attacks burn for 150 true damage over 5 seconds, and also reveals the target for the duration. *This stack only lasts 180 seconds.*

### Twisted Treeline buffs:

---

#### [Crest of Crushing Wrath](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crest_of_Crushing_Wrath)

Granted by killing Vilemaw, the boss monster located at the top of the map.

- Bonus health regeneration
- Bonus mana regeneration
- Increased attack speed
- 20% Cool-down reduction

(No source can be found with exact details, but this unspecific info was found on the wiki)

*Lasts for 2:00 minutes or 2:24 with Runic Affinity.*

*If slain, buff is lost and not transferred (same as Hand of Baron on Summoner's Rift).*

#### [Altar buffs](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Altar)

One Altar

- +3 gold on unit kill

Two Altars

- +3 gold on unit kill
- Adds +10% attack damage and ability power

*Capturing an altar will give +80 gold to all players on the capturing team and vision of the altar*

*Buff is permanent as long as you own the altar.*

*Altars first open at the 3 minute mark and are locked for 90 seconds after being captured. Once unlocked the other team can capture and lock it for themselves, but the same altar cannot be captured by the team that already owns it.*

### Crystal Scar (Dominion) Buffs:

---

#### [Shrines](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Speed_Shrines)

- When walking over shrines, the player gains a 30% movement buff.

*These areas are neutral, so both teams can utilize them.*

*lasts 10 seconds or 12 with runic affinity*

#### [Health Relics](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Health_Relic)

- "It seems to give you 15 + 1.25 x level % of your champion's max health (Pending Testing.)"
- Add 2 points to your personal score

*These areas are neutral, so both teams can utilize them.*

#### [Greater Relic / Storm Shield](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Shield)

Increased champion model size.
 - A shield of 212.5 (+12.5 x level).
 - Passively detonate a lightning blast inflicting 90 (+10 x level) magic damage on champion auto attacks and damaging spells.

#### [Mark of the Conqueror](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mark_of_the_Conqueror)

This buff is granted to the first team to complete a "quest" on dominion.

- +10% to all damage types

*50 seconds or 1 minute with Runic Affinity*

### Proving Grounds (ARAM) Buffs:

---

(Same as Dominion Health Relic)

#### [Health Relics](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Health_Relic)

- On both maps, it seems to give you 15 + 1.25 x level % of your champion's max health (Pending Testing.)

*These areas are neutral, so both teams can utilize them.*

---

***FORMATTING TAKEN FROM [@theorise](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/33970/37612)***

Comment: Deleted the old answer to avoid confusion. Nice stuff!

Comment: @Katustrawfic were there any changes with Pre-Season 4 update?

Comment: how long does red buff slow for and how many ticks of the true damage is dealt?

Comment: I dont follow LoL anymore, but are there updates for S5?

Comment: @F.S. Yes they have been changes since this answer was made, will  be updated shortly.

Answer (score 0):

While @theorise explained the actual buffs, I want to touch briefly on your assumption that the golem buff (I'll call it blue for the sake of briefness) goes to AP champions and the lizard buff (henceforth, red) goes to AD champions.

Blue will increase your cooldown reduction, letting you use spells more often, and give you mana regen, so AD casters (Talon, Zed, Urgot etc.) will get full benefit from it. It's not something AP-specific. In fact some AD carries like Ezreal will also get full benefit in a poke comp (5 man team built around poking, think Jayce, Ezreal, Nidalee etc) since he can Mystic Shot more often and not run out of mana.

Red on the other hand only scales with your attack speed, and while that *can* scream AD carry, there's plenty of pure AP casters that scale with attack speed even more than AD carries (both ranged and melee, think Kayle, Teemo, Diana). Your typical AD carry will only really build a Phantom Dancer (or Blade of the Ruined King nowadays) for attack speed, where an AP Kayle will have a Nashor's Blade, Teemo will have Hurricane etc, getting even more out of that red buff.

I guess I should also mention blue can be good even on mana-less champions, like energy users (Akali!), or just plain resourceless (Riven!). The cooldown reduction is really noticeable.