# What are the exact buffs that baron gives?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What effect do neutral buffs have in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33968/what-effect-do-neutral-buffs-have-in-league-of-legends)

I just saw baron getting taken by jpak and freinds in the ggClassic semifinals, so I was just curious what baron gives as a buff, experience, gold, etc.

Comment: Duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33968/what-effect-do-neutral-buffs-have-in-league-of-legends

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a few statistic/number questions here so I'll go ahead and link the LoL wiki.  This site is updated almost immediately after changes occur in patches/hotfixes and is generally very reliable.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Baron_Nashor

> (Passive): On death, Baron Nashor awards the team who slew him 300
>   gold and 900 experience per head, and empowers them with a buff for 4
>   minutes. The buff grants the wearer 40 attack damage, 40 ability
>   power, 3% of their maximum health as hp/5 and 1% of their maximum mana
>   as mp/5. The enemy who scored the last hit is awarded a bonus 25 gold.

Comment: please quote the information from the site you link to in case it goes down so the information is persisted on this site

Comment: Sorry about that.  Forgot there was a quote function as well :P